# Solve an integral with product of trigonometric functions squared

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral. It is possible to integrate by parts but that is way too long so I got another idea.

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\:\frac{\cos ^2\left(2θ\right)\cos ^2\left(θ\right)}{4}\:d\theta $$

Applying these identities it is supposed to be easier. However, I am stuck. This is what I tried:

(1) $\cos(x)\cos(y)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(y+x)+\cos(y−x))$

(2) $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x)+1)$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\cos^2\left(\theta \right)\cos^2\left(2\theta \right)\,d\theta $$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(2\theta \right)+1\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(4\theta \:\right)\right)+1\right)\,d\theta $$

I tried to use some software to help, and somehow we get to this, that is very easy to integrate:
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\:\frac{\cos\left(6\theta \:\right)+2\cos\left(4\theta \:\right)+3\cos\left(2\theta \:\right)}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\:d\theta \:$$

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close. The next step is to expand the brackets and then use the 'Product to Sum' formula

$$
\cos(A)\cos(B) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)\right).
$$

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but in that cause I would get where I started with the $cos^2$ again I think? I will keep trying anyway, thank you for the help!

Comment: It shouldn't take you back to $\cos^2$.You'll get something like 

$$
\dfrac{1}{4}\int \dfrac 1 4 \cos4\theta\cos2\theta + ... d\theta.
$$ 

Then, use the product to sum formula with $A=4\theta, B=2\theta$. That will get rid of the $\cos4\theta\cos4\theta$ term, and you'll be left with the straightforward integration that your software package gave.

Comment: By the way, one of your formulae has a misplaced parenthesis. 

$$
\frac{1}{4}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(2\theta \right)+1\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(4\theta \:\right)\right)+1\right)\,d\theta
$$

should be

$$
\frac{1}{4}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(2\theta \right)+1\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(4\theta \:\right)+1\right)\right)\,d\theta
$$

Comment: You are right! (with both things). Thank you. I advanced a lot, but can't go any further than: $$\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}\:\left(\frac{cos6\theta +2cos4\theta +3cos2\theta +2}{4}\right)\:d\theta \:$$ Did you try if it is actually possible to get the final integral the software shows?

Comment: I'm not sure about the 1/8 that the software package gave. Are you sure that's right?

Anyway, I suggest that you press on with what you have. I haven't cheked your calculation above, but the method is correct, so double check it. If it's correct, you should be on easy street now. 

Take the $1/4$ outside the integral sign (when you do, it should give you $1/16, I think)$, integrate term-by-term, evaluate at $\pi/4$ (evaluation at $0$ will give zero for all terms), and voila!

If you're still stuck, I'll try to post a solution tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: I could find the result, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy to integrate trigonometric polynomials in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos \theta$ is to linearise them.

An easy method  consists in using the definition of these functions  in terms of complex exponentials:
$$\sin\theta=\frac{\mathrm e^{i\theta}-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}}{2i}, \quad \cos \theta=\frac{\mathrm e^{i\theta}+\mathrm e^{-i\theta}}{2} .$$

To have lighter notations, set $\;u=\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, $\;\bar u=\mathrm e^{-i\theta}$, so that $\sin \theta=\frac1{2i}(u-\bar u)$, $\;\cos\theta=\frac 12(u+\bar u)$. It's simpler to make the calculations with $u$ and $\bar u$, if we take into account the following relations:
$$u^n-\bar u^n=2i\sin(n\theta), \qquad u^n+\bar u^n=2\cos(n\theta),\qquad u\,\bar u=1. $$

I'll show how it begins in your case:
\begin{align}
\bigl(\cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)\bigr)^2&=\bigl(\tfrac14(u+\bar u)(u^2+\bar u^2)\bigr)^2=\tfrac1{16}\bigl((u^3+u\,\bar u^2+\bar u\,u^2+\bar u^3)\bigr)^2=\tfrac 1{16}\bigl(u^3+\bar u^3+ u+\bar u\bigr)^2\\[1ex]
&=\tfrac 1{16}\bigl(u^6+\bar u^6+ u^2+\bar u^2+2(u^3\,\bar u^3+u^4+u^3\,\bar u+\bar u^3u+\bar u^4+u\,\bar u)\bigr)\\[1ex]
&=\tfrac 1{16}\bigl(u^6+\bar u^6+2(u^4+\bar u^4)+3(u^2+\bar u^2)+4\bigr) =\dotsm
\end{align}

Comment: That would work too, thank you!